# C++ const and mutable functions with the same name

Tags: c++, constants, overloading

Considering the following piece of code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Object
{
public:
    Object() {}

    void Print() const
    {
        cout << "const" << endl;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        cout << "mutable" << endl;
    }
};

void print_obj(const Object& obj)
{
    obj.Print();
}

int main()
{
    Object       obj1;
    const Object obj2;
    Object*const pobj1 = &obj1;
    
    print_obj(obj1);
    print_obj(obj2);
    
    obj1.Print();
    obj2.Print();
    
    pobj1->Print();
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
const
const
mutable
const
mutable
```

I am wondering, how does C++ decide which method to invoke, when facing many mutable methods with the same name?

Comment: I hope the real answer you're taking away from this is "I'd never do anything that perverse - even if I *could* get away with it." ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
print_obj(obj1); 
print_obj(obj2);
```

The function to be called is evaluated on the basis of the *cv-qualifier*(`const`/`volatile`) of the passed object. Note that *cv-qualifiers* are considered while function overload resolution.
If passed object is `const`, function receiving `const` argument is selected.If passed object is non-const then function receiving non-const argument is selected.

---

```
obj1.Print();   
obj2.Print();   
pobj1->Print();
```

If the object is `const` then only call `const` member function can be called.
If the object is non-const then the non-const version is prefferred over the `const` version.

The rules are clearly specified by the standard.

Reference:
**C++03 standard:

§13.3.1 Candidate functions and argument lists:**

> For non-static member functions, the type of the implicit object parameter is “reference to cv `X`” where `X` is the class of which the function is a member and cv is the cv-qualification on the member function declaration. [Example: for a const member function of class `X`, the extra parameter is assumed to have type “reference to const `X`”. ]

So if the object is `const` compiler will pick version of member function which has implicit object parameter of type *reference to const `Object`* which is const version of `Print()`.

Comment: The C++11 standard expands this to rvalue-reference implicit object parameters in the same way as expected.

Answer (score 3):

The same way all function overloading works.

When considering a member function for overloading, it includes the implicit `this` parameter. If the function is declared `const`, then the `this` parameter is `const Object *`. If the function is not `const` then the `this` parameter is `Object *`. Since `const` qualifiers affect the function overloading rules, this means that the `const`ness of a function also affects the function overloading rules.

In your specific example, `print_obj(obj1)` prints `const` because `print_obj()` is declared as taking a `const Object&`, which means it will always invoke the `const` version of `Print()`. Same thing with `print_obj(obj2)`.

`obj1.Print()` prints `mutable` because `obj1` is not `const`, therefore the non-`const` version of `Print()` is a better match and is picked for the function overload resolution.

`obj2.Print()` prints `const` because `obj2` is `const`, therefore the `const` version of `Print()` is the only function overload that's suitable.

`pobj1->Print()` prints `mutable` because `*pboj1` is a non-`const` value, so the non-`const` version of `Print()` is picked for the function overload resolution.

The simplest way to think about it is, what would happen if you simply had

```
void Print(Object &obj);
void Print(const Object &obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind that, for a normal object if a non-`const` version is available then non-`const` version is chosen; otherwise `const` version is chosen. Below is the analysis:

```
print_obj(obj1); // print_obj() receives const argument, so `const` is chosen
print_obj(obj2); // same as above

obj1.Print();  // obj1 is not const, so non-const version is chosen
obj2.Print();  // obj2 is const, so must choose const version

pobj1->Print(); // pobj1 is a const pointer pointing to non-const object, so non-const version is chosen
```

Answer (score -2):

It would prefer a const method to non-const if both would do.

Same works for volatile, BTW.